# how to use the listbox value to update textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an Access form with a list-box consisting of two columns and its MultiSelect property is set to None.  I need to update 2 text-box using this list-box where if the user select an item from it the value of its first column is used to update one text-box and the value of the second column is used to update another text-box , something like :

```
Private Sub listbox_AfterUpdate()

Dim colval1 As String
Dim colval2 As String

colval1 = Me.listbox.column(1).Value
colval2 = Me.listbox.column(2).Value

Me.[textbox1] = colval1 
Me.[textbox2] = colval2 


End Sub
```

I just don't know how to get the value of this list-box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List box column numbering starts from zero, so the first column value is accessible as `Me.listbox.Column(0)`.  Access throws an error (*"object required"*) when you append `.Value` after the column.

Also you shouldn't need variables to store the column values before you assign them to the text boxes.  You can assign the column values to the text boxes directly.

```vb
Private Sub listbox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.[textbox1] = Me.listbox.Column(0)
    Me.[textbox2] = Me.listbox.Column(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Crazy VBA:

```
Me.[textbox3] =Me.listbox
```

will give you your value.